# Wordpress Styling

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am new to using Wordpress as a developer as opposed to just using the dashbord but am struggling to understand a few things and would really appreciate some help.

For a site that does not require a blog - do you just create custom/specific page templates for each page that your site requires?

If so - presumably you code the content directly. But then how does the client edit their website's about page or any other page for example - because doing it through the dashboard isn't going to use the necessary CSS hooks without using classes, id's and HTML?

As a beginner to Wordpress -  I can't see that posts are used on sites that don't have a blog, but am I correct or is using posts the way a client can edit content on their site, but just have posts styled to look like normal content?

Or am I wrong in thinking a company (I am starting as an intern at a web dev company that use WordPress) provides the tools or at least configures WordPress to enable the client to change content?

Any help getting me to understand the basic concept and way a developer would create a custom WordPress site would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more suited for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thank you, I had no idea this existed. Will put it on there now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `page.php`. In WordPress everyone create at least one custom template type to get wider design for custom pages.
[You can refer here for more info.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates)

Answer (score 0):

Use Advanced Custom Fields with page templates. Say you are making an About page, call that template about and select that template in the backend editor. Once you save the page, the acf fields will show up and you can populate the content.

ACF: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

Page Templates: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/